# How to detect whether it is in SwiftUI Preview mode in code to skip loading some resources?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

After adding some resources managers such as accessing the document directory in my code base (with failure assertion if cannot read the document directory). It is not possible to use SwiftUI preview.

How can we detect whether it is running in the SwiftUI Preview mode? In this mode, I don't want to load any extra resources.

Comment: I feel it is like design issue, because, actually, there is no reason to detect preview mode. It preview mode you construct environment for view as you want, so if view does not depend on reading unavailable resources, but from some view model, which is responsible for providing resources, then in preview mode you can just inject view model, that do not use unavailable resources, but just some predefined data. As a result - no needs to know that view is in preview.

Comment: @Asperi How about global resources which should be initialized during app boot? These resources are initialized in SceneDelegate or AppDelegate and I don't think SwiftUI preview should execute them.

Comment: Your view shouldn't be accessing global resources. You should pass all of the view's requirements to it, either as initializer arguments or via the `Environment`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a live microphone which defeats the preview.  There is a need for a preview check.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is better to redesign your architecture to inject and load resources **only** when needed, here is how you can check if you are currently on the "preview mode" at runtime:

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] == "1" { /* You are in the preview */ }
```